# Horizontal CSS gradients?

Tags: css

I Want to have a gradient as the background of my webpage. I have figured out how to make the gradient vertical but I want it to be horizontal.

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 25%, 0% 0%, from(rgb(176, 196, 222)), to(rgb(255, 255, 255)));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(153, 255, 51) 25%, rgb(255, 102, 51) 80%);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For `-webkit-gradient` you define the direction by using the two points (the 2nd and 3rd argument in your case), and for `-moz-linear-gradient` it's defined by the starting point only (the first argument). So to turn those gradients to horizontal ones, you'd do:

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 25% 0%, 0% 0%, from(rgb(176, 196, 222)), to(rgb(255, 255, 255)));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center right, rgb(153, 255, 51) 25%, rgb(255, 102, 51) 80%);
```

(You might have to tweak your color values because you're defining the points differently for each browser. It could be easier if you set the points to `center right, center left` for Webkit as well to match Mozilla.)

Comment: Yes. Use this line for Internet Explorer 8 and 9:

`-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=1, startColorstr='#b0c4de', endColorstr='#ffffff')"`